# infoWindow in google map not showing properly in an iPhone phonegap app

Tags: iphone, google-maps, cordova, google-api

I am showing custom marker with click event on it. It shows information when I clicked but the info window is not showing well. I used some css in it. I also need to customize it further. This map is shown in phonegap app in iPhone (iOS 5). Every other thing working find (including direction, GPS).
I have used google map js v3 API.
I got this output.
[image: output]

How to show correct infoWindow? And customize as my need.

here is the code

```
function setMap(myLat, myLng){
    // Define Marker properties
 var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/pick.png',
      new google.maps.Size(30, 40),
      // The origin for this image is 0,0.
      new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at 9,36.
      new google.maps.Point(9, 36)
      );

  var my_place = new google.maps.LatLng(myLat, myLng);
  var myOptions = {
  zoom:14,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  mapTypeControl: false,
  center: my_place
  }
  mer_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mer_map_canvas"), myOptions);
  mer_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                              position: my_place, 
                              map: mer_map,
                              clickable : true,
                              animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                              icon: image
                              });
var contentString = '<div id="mer_map_info" style="border:3px solid red; color:#FFF; background-color:#000;"><p>this is just a test...</p></div>';
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
});

google.maps.event.addListener(mer_marker, 'click', function(event) {
        infowindow.open(mer_map,mer_marker);
        });}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try. I had a similar problem with phonegap and google maps.

```
#map_canvas img {
max-width: none;
}
```